# Unused cookie dough

Tags: freezing, cookies

I arranged my cookie dough on the pan when I noticed I was out of gas. I put the pan in the freezer and ended up without gas yesterday.

Its the next day now and the cookie dough is still arranged on the pan (in the freezer). The recipe has egg, baking powder and baking soda. I have gas now but I'm worried the dough is wasted,

Is it still good? can I still use it? is there any remedy?

Answer (score 6):

What you've done is perfectly fine, and your cookies will bake as usual, although they make need an extra few minutes in the oven. As a matter of fact, the method you've used is what is recommended for scooped cookies, when you you want to prep in advance and bake days, or weeks, later. Since your baking sheet has also been chilled, you might let it sit at room temperature for a bit, rather than transferring it directly from freezer to oven.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Will do just as you have said.

Comment: Little comment i forgot to mention though, the cookie dough is rolled and flattened on the pan, its not in a ziplock or any other storage.

Comment: @Bo-Learner that's fine, too. By the time the sheet goes into the oven, the dough will be defrosted, or nearly so. Just watch the baking, as you usually would, so that they don't overcook.